# Handling Expiry Date using RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, restsharp

I am consuming an API using RestSharp on .Net Core 3.1. Its is mandatory for the token generated to be re-used by the relevant endpoints endlessly until the expiry date reaches where a new token will be generated again.
The issue I am facing is that, at times the enpoints work perfectly but again at certain moments they all fail. Got me thinking that maybe the token is regenerated before the expiry date and the endpoints don't receive this new token.

Below is my Controller for getting the token.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public string GetToken()
    {
        var _Url = "xx";
        var _Username = "xx";
        var _Password = "xx";

        _memoryCache.TryGetValue("ApiAuthenticationToken", out string token);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            var _Client = new RestClient(_Url);
            var _Request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
            {
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
            };
            _Request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
            _Request.AddParameter("username", _Username);
            _Request.AddParameter("password", _Password);

            var _Response = _Client.Execute<MyToken>(_Request);

            if (_Response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                token = _Response.Data.token;
                _ = _memoryCache.Set("ApiAuthenticationToken", token);
            }
            else
            {
                throw _Response.ErrorException;
            }

            return token;
        }

        return token;
    }
}
```

Below is an example of one endpoint consuming the token.

```
[Route("api/Certificate/Cancel")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class CancelCertificateController : HomeController
{
    private IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public CancelCertificateController(IMemoryCache memoryCache) : base(memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] CancelCert cancelCert)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("xx");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8");
        request.Parameters.Clear();
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", GetToken()));
        request.AddHeader("ClientID", "xxx");
        request.AddJsonBody(cancelCert);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        var jObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
        if (Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
        {
            return new JsonResult(jObject);
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Is there an alternative way of handling such requests that insist that a token is generated once and used until it expires or is my code missing something?

Comment: Where's the code that determines whether that handles detection of expiry and refreshing of the auth token?

Comment: You should really move all code that deals with the API into a single service so that your controller methods are as small as possible and then refactor the code again to further remove any duplication of code. Once done, you should attempt to write some thread-safe way of refreshing the auth token.